# Kotlin/React component not updating

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, kotlin-js

```
external interface SquareProps: Props {
    var value: String
    var theHandleClick: () -> Unit
}

val Square: FC<SquareProps> = FC<SquareProps> {props ->
    button {
        +"${props.value}"
        className = ClassName("square")
        onClick = {
            props.theHandleClick()
            
        }
    }
}

external interface MySquareProps: Props  {
    var i: Int
}
var Board: FC<Props> = FC<Props> {
    val status: String = "Next player: X"
    var squares: MutableList<String> by useState((0 until 9).map { "" } as MutableList<String>)
    var MySquare: FC<MySquareProps> = FC<MySquareProps> {
        Square {
            value = squares[it.i]
            theHandleClick = {
                squares[it.i] = "X"
            }
        }
    }
    div {
        div {
            className = ClassName("status")
            +status
        }
        div {
            className = ClassName("board-row")
            MySquare {
                i = 0
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Imports and extra board squares are omitted and multiple files are merged into one block of code here.

Trying to port the react tic tac toe example to Kotlin to learn a bit more about Kotlin/JS and add a tic-tac-toe game to my school's website.

`squares` is updating but the actual text inside the components is not

Comment: there is not jsx in kotlin, you can try https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-mpp/

Comment: @lisonge DSL is Kotlin's equivalent to JSX